# Thready safety of Maps, used privately inside application scoped bean & only for ready purposes after once building

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf, concurrency, thread-safety

I have an `@ApplicationScoped` bean for all users, that stores the ids-> names & vice versa in `Trove` & `java.util` maps.

I just build the maps once at construction of bean *or (in case of manual refresh by the website admin).*

Inside the bean methods, I am just using the `get()` with the maps, so not modifying the map. Is this going to be thread safe since it is used only for ready purposes? I am not sharing the maps with any other beans outside & not modifying the maps(adding/removing entries) anytime in my code.

Also, Is it neccesary in this case to make the fields final ?

**Bean code as follows:**

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean(name="directory", eager=true)
public class directory {

    private static TIntObjectHashMap<String> idsToNamesMap;
    private static TreeMap<String, Integer> namesToIdsMap;

    @PostConstruct
    public void buildDirectory(){
        // building directory here ....
    }

    public String getName(int topicId){
        return idsToNamesMap.get(topicId);
    }    

    public List<Entry<String, Integer>> searchTopicsByName(String query){
        return new ArrayList(namesToIdsMap.subMap(query, true, query+"z", true).entrySet());
    }        
}
```

---

Comment: Yes, Since you are not modifying the values in the maps, you will be fine.

Comment: If he's not modifying the contents of the maps, then the maps should be empty and quite useless.  Surely he's populating the maps.  And if he is, he needs to consider memory visibility.  Just because something is done in a constructor doesn't mean it doesn't count as a write access to the collection.  I'm not saying there's a problem, just pointing out that it's not just as simple as "well later on in the main program I never modify them!"  The beginning of the program counts too.

Comment: yes definitely I am populating the maps but I believe it is just a single thread that will do so for just once when the bean is being constructed (since `buildDirectory` is annotated with `@PostConstruct`)

Comment: @MikeClark If building the maps is not multithreaded, then where is issue?

Comment: @YoussefG. If the worker threads that will read from the maps were started before the maps were initialized, then there is a possible memory visibility issue, even if there is a guarantee that the worker threads will NOT 'read' from the maps until after the initialization stage of the maps.  He is not synchronizing manually anywhere, so he would be relying entirely on thread-creation as a memory flush point.  If worker thread creation happens earlier in the lifecycle than map init, then there is no memory flush point between the map-initializing thread and the map-reader-threads.

Comment: @MikeClark: Could you please comment about how I can resolve this issue ? Do I need to synchronize the map constructing block of code or how?

Comment: @MikeClark: would making the `buildDirectory()` method synchronized do fine ?

Comment: @user as long as reading is not concurrent with writing, you could just mark the `idsToNamesMap` and `namesToIdsMap` as `final` (prefer if final if final works) or otherwise `volatile`.  Accessing a `volatile` field serves as a memory flush point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to declare them volatile or protect with any kind of synchronization in this case. As long as the constructing thread will build them and synchronize with the main memory.

For that the constructing thread need just to make a single write to a volatile variable or enter/exit a synchronization lock. This will pass a memory barrier and all local thread data will be in the main thread. Then it will be safe for all other threads to read this data.

Even more - unnecessary volatile or synchronization block - costs a serious performance penalty - on each access to the variable it will pass the memory barrier - which is an expensive operation

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more explicitly about how to achieve that, if possible, through a simple example?

Comment: For example Spring framework and J2EE containers already do that. When you declare a field populated with annotations you don't have to worry about this. But if you want to be safe, you can add simple synchronized(this) {} at the end of you @PostConstruct method to flush all local variables to the main memory. (I don't think you need to do that, though).

Comment: so, as you say, everything is OK in my code & I dont need to chnage anything !? not make anything the maps fields even `volatile` ?

Comment: And what about the memory visibility issues that MikeClark has been pointing to in the comments to the question ?

Comment: He means that other threads might read dirty data from the main memory. In general that is correct, if the data is changed during the application lifetime. If the data is built on initialization, and is never changed afterwards - that is not a concern. I agree, that it's better to declare fields non-static, though.

Comment: Even more - unnecessary volatile or synchronization block - is a serious performance penalty - on each access to the variable it will pass the memory barrier - which is an expensive operation.

Comment: +1 you are absolutely right, we can avoid `volatile` due to the behavior you describe. The key is that the variables whose visibility you care about must share the monitor that the thread synchronizes on.  That becomes true once the maps are made non-`static`. So that plus synchronization in the course of building (i.e. making `buildDirectory()` a `synchronized` method) would work.  This produces a higher performing solution than the one I initially proposed because there's no more `volatile` - you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

There could be a visibility issue after the object is constructed.  That is, in the immediate aftermath of your constructor calls, the maps may appear populated to the thread that populated them, but not necessarily to other threads, at least not right away.  This type of issue is extensively discussed in chapter 3 of [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601). However, I think that if you declare the maps as `volatile`:

```
private static volatile TIntObjectHashMap<String> idsToNamesMap;
private static volatile TreeMap<String, Integer> namesToIdsMap;
```

You should be OK.

**Update**

I just realized something while looking at your code again.  The maps are `static` - why are they being populated in an instance context by a constructor?  First off, it is confusing to the reader.  Second, if more than one instance of the object is created, then you will have additional writes to the maps, not just one, possibly while other threads are reading them.

You should either make them non-`static`, or populate them in a [static initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: Thanks sparc_spread ! Yes that makes sense. Actually  I just made them static probably to access them via static methods but I guess rather than initializing within static blocks it would make more sense to make the them non-static instead as the bean is already application scoped & is just single instance for entire application so static anyway doesn't add any value to it.

Comment: @user If you initialized them in a class initializer (`static` block), all of the thread visibility issues would be dealt with automatically (as there is a memory barrier around class initialization). You could still access these static structures from instance methods, as that makes more sense in a bean context.

Comment: @erickson: Thanks for comment! So in case I populate the bean's maps(from DB) inside the static block, then wont I need to make the fields volatile or make any other changes?

Comment: Also I am a bit unconfident about whther populating data from DB within static blocks is a right idea !?

Comment: @user - glad to help!  @erickson is correct, class initialization guarantees visibility because of the memory barrier at that stage of execution, so you would not need `volatile` if you did that.  Now, re your other question, are you saying that the population of the maps is using the results of a database call?  If so, then I agree with you that making database calls from a static initialization block is risky.  In that case, I'd choose `volatile`, non-`static`, initialize in constructor, and rely on the bean scope / guarantee of singleton-ness that you mentioned before.

Comment: @sparc_spread: Thanks. Is it possible if I can somehow, even avoid the `volatile` fields, so that the read operations always deliver max performance. As a tradeoff, I don't mind synchronizing the build operations or anything that makes building maps more costly

Comment: @user:  keep in mind that `volatile` reads are still less expensive than `synchronized` reads.  But doing `synchronized` only once at startup is even less expensive than those :-)  So your solution makes sense.

Comment: so, you mean just making the buildDirectory() method `synchronized` would solve all these  issues, right ?

Comment: Yes.  The one additional qualification to add to what @Eugene explained is that for the synchronization to memory to work, the variables whose visibility you are concerned about must share the same monitor that the thread is synchronizing on.  If the maps are made into instance variables (i.e. non-`static`), and the `buildDirectory()` method is made `synchronized`, then the monitor is the same:  the monitor for the instance.  So yes, just make `buildDirectory()` synchronized and you are done.

Comment: So, summary of solution is:  (1) Make the maps into instance variables; (2) Make `buildDirectory()` into a `synchronized` method; (3) Ensure via your container that your class is a singleton.  No need for `volatile`, or for `synchronized` after the single call to `buildDirectory()`.